# Spring Custom Annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am not sure if it is possible to easily do what I am wanting to do. I have the following controller which works as both a rest and websocket controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("rest/user")
@MessageMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    @MessageMapping("/list")
    @SendTo("/channel/user")
    public apiResImpl list() {      
        Iterable<UserImpl> users = userRepo.findAll();  
        return users != null ? new apiResImpl("success", users) :  new apiResImpl("fail");
    }

 ...
```

I would like to wrap several of these annotations up in a two custom annotations @ApiController and @ApiMapping

Something like this:

```
@ApiController("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

     @ApiMapping("/list")
     public apiResImpl list() {     
         Iterable<UserImpl> users = userRepo.findAll(); 
         return users != null ? new apiResImpl("success", users) :  new apiResImpl("fail");
     }

 ...
```

The issue I am having is being able to pass values into the custom annotation that are internally handed to the spring annotations. What would this @interface look like? Any examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Documented
@RequestMapping // meta-annotated RequestMapping 
@MessageMapping // meta-annotated MessageMapping
public @interface ApiController {

     @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "value") // -> alias for RequestMapping value attribute
     String[] value() default {};

     @AliasFor(annotation = MessageMapping.class, attribute = "value") // -> alias for MessageMapping value attribute
     String[] mvalue() default{};   
}


@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Documented
@RequestMapping
@MessageMapping
public @interface ApiMapping {

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "value")
    String[] value() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = MessageMapping.class, attribute = "value")
    String[] mvalue() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "method")
    RequestMethod[] method() default {};
}
```

Referring the below link I have come up with this solution, using this technique we can give an alias to the attribute of meta-annotated annotation i.e., (here RequestMapping, MessageMapping).

One disadvantage of AliasFor is, it is non repeatable annotation.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#_core_container_improvements_2

Answer (score 0):

```
         @Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/*")
@MessageMapping
public @interface ApiController {
    String value() default "";

}
```

Comment: This answer really got my hopes up :) but it did not seem to do the trick. Rest calls return 404 and websocket messages go unanswered. "String value()" does not seem to 1) get appended onto RequestMappiing's value, and 2) does not seem to be communicated to MessageMapping's value property.